# Energy Functional on Regular Curves

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, calculus-of-variations, curves

Consider the energy functional $$ E(\gamma) = \int_I ||\gamma^{'}||^{2}dt$$ on regular curves $\eta$ : I $\rightarrow$ S$^{2}$

i) Show that if γ$_s$ : I → S
$^2$
is any variation of γ = γ$_0$ by curves on S$^{2}$
then
its variational vector field V = γ' satisfies < V, γ >= 0.

**i)** So for this part we basically show that if we have a variation, $\gamma_s$, which is just $\gamma(t + \eta*s)$ (with s=0 yields $\gamma$) then the field is orthogonal to the curve? Not really sure how to represent V such that I can show when it's dotted with $\gamma$ it's equal to zero. Or is it some property about the system?

ii) Let V : I → R$^3$ be smooth with < V, γ >= 0. Show that there is a variation
γ$_s$ of γ by curves on S$^2$
. Moreover, if V is compactly supported so will be
γs.

**ii)** This is essentially the converse of the previous statement right? So that if the inner product of (essentially) $\gamma$ and $\gamma^{'}$ is equal to zero then we much have a variation $\gamma_s$ on $\gamma$. How do we go about this?

iii) Characterize the critical points of E under compactly supported variations
γ$_s$ by curves on S$^2$

**iii)** So for this part we employ the Euler-Lagrange equations to find the critical points then we employ some tactic which is analogous to the 2nd derivative test in order to classify the critical points correct? And if so can anyone describe the process? I think it's something like showing the 2nd variation is always positive or negative but I don't know what or how to find the 2nd variation.

Comment: For (i): notice that the vector $\gamma$, at any point, points from the center of the ball to its surface, and so is radial; and that its variation field $V$ must be a tangent vector to the sphere. For (iii), I am pretty sure you are over-thinking the problem. The question is probably asking about the geometric meaning (as curves on $S^2$) of the critical points; second variation shouldn't come into play here.

Comment: Ahh okay I see. I was thinking about the fact that on a sphere the tangent vector and position vector are orthogonal but was thinking too much about the nature of the variation rather than the fact that the variation is on the sphere. For iii) I think I got something like the critical points are all constant speed geodesics

Comment: Do you know if ii) is just as easy as restating the argument for part i) in it's converse? It doesn't seem like it should be that easy. Especially given it asks to show that the variations are compactly supported if the variational field is compactly supported. Do you have any insight you can offer for part ii)?

Comment: Good, so you've got (i) and (iii). For (ii) you can actually write down an _explicit_ formula for the variations $\gamma_s$. Basically: if $a, b$ are orthogonal unit vectors, then $a \cos\theta + b\sin\theta$ are unit vectors in the plane spanned by $a$ and $b$ that equals $a$ when $\theta = 0$.

Comment: Would you mind elucidating this explicit formula? I only ask because I've only ever know variations as I defined them in my question -- as having the 2nd parameter which can be fine turned. We haven't done much concrete with the calculus of variations. And so what you're saying is since V and $\gamma$ are orthogonal we may write them as Vcos($\theta$) + $\gamma$sin($\theta$) and so then when our angle is  we have our tangent vector and when our angle is perpendicular to that at 90 or 270 degrees we are left with only the position (radial) vector?

Comment: Hint: $\theta$ is almost $s$. The problem is that $V$ is not a unit vector in general, and so if you set $\gamma_s = \gamma \cos(s) + V \sin s$, while you have $\frac{d}{ds} \gamma_s |_{s =0} = V$, you don't have that $\gamma_s \in S^2$. But you can fix that by changing both $V$ (to make it unit) and $\theta$ (so that taking $d/ds$ and evaluating at $0$ you still get $V$).

Comment: Ahh okay I see what you're saying. I believe my professor said to assume arclength parameterization for all problems so would that change V to being a unit vector? or unit vector field (whatever it is, specifically)